# java socketing programming , ip behind wifi

Tags: java, sockets, ip, wifi, nat

I am implementing a Java socket programming application with a server behind a public wifi access. I am having problem with using client to access this server, which is the NAT issue I assume. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe your firewall is blocking incoming connections? If so, the server won't be able to accept clients. Or maybe you didn't configure port forwarding in your wifi AP settings?

Answer (score 0):

I would first configure your router to map a public port to your server IP and Java service port (the ports don't necessarily need to be the same: the router will translate the traffic before it reaches your Java server).  The client then connects to your public IP using that public port.

If that works OK, I recommend looking at some Java libraries to leverage UPnP, NAT-PMP, or IGDP that can allow your Java service to map its own port on home routers automatically.

Comment: Thank you, the issue is the WIFI i access is a public WIFI, which means I can't configure it...

Comment: You may want to try a 3rd party Java library for UPnP/NAT-PMP then... although it's very likely the access router has that capability disabled.